# SQL syntax error ZF1

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I'm getting an error but I just can't seem to find the error myself.
Maybe does someone of you guys knows the solution.

My query:

```
return $db->fetchAll("SELECT DISTINCT *, 
MATCH(k.naam, k.plaats) 
AGAINST('{$newQ}' 
IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
as score 
FROM klant k 
WHERE MATCH(k.naam, k.plaats) 
AGAINST('{$newQ}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR code = '{$q}' 
AND bedrijf_id = '{$bedrijf}' 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT " . intval($limit));
```

And my error:

```
Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: 
Syntax error or access violation: 1064 syntax error, 
unexpected $end, expecting FTS_TERM or FTS_NUMB or '*', 
query was: SELECT DISTINCT *, MATCH(k.naam, k.plaats) AGAINST('*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM klant k WHERE MATCH(k.naam, k.plaats) AGAINST('*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) OR code = '' AND bedrijf_id = '1' ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
```

The query looks absolutely fine to me, can someone point me where I should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` returns a double, not a boolean - you're missing a restriction on its return value in your `where` clause:

```
return $db->fetchAll("SELECT DISTINCT *, 
MATCH(k.naam, k.plaats) 
AGAINST('{$newQ}' 
IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
as score 
FROM klant k 
WHERE MATCH(k.naam, k.plaats) 
AGAINST('{$newQ}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
HAVING relevance > 0 -- Missing from the OP
OR code = '{$q}' 
AND bedrijf_id = '{$bedrijf}' 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT " . intval($limit));
```

Comment: I found out it was a little combined problem with zend update and my parameter passing, but this is also a good point which I had forgotten. Therefore I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today. I found out that the cause is the format of the MATCH() parameters. Therefore, in your case, whats causing the error is the value you pass into **{$newQ}**.

To find out the syntax for MATCH(), check out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html